# What's the difference between a vocoder and a harmonizer?

Tags: audio, signal-processing

As a follow-up to this question: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/351/what-is-the-difference-between-autotune-and-a-vocoder, let's get into the nitty-gritty about vocoders and harmonizers.

For example, in Imogen Heap's famous Hide and Seek song, she's apparently using a harmonizer, not a vocoder. I also read that the harmonizer as a live performance device can be very unpredictable - to the point that Imogen won't even use it in a live performance.

So how does the harmonizer differ from the vocoder, where you can just play the keys and get the source tuned to the carrier frequency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"...from the vocoder, where you can just play the keys and get the source tuned to the carrier frequency?"

That's not what a vocoder actually does. A vocoder analyses the *rough frequency spectrum* of a (source) signal, and uses this spectrum as a kind of equalizer envelope for the processing of another (carrier) signal. If the carrier had a very even frequency spectrum before, it will thereby pretty much take over/copy the frequency distribution of the source. The source itself is not processed in any way at all, apart from being analysed.
The carrier is usually such an even-spectrum synthesizer sound, but you can use any kind of signal. For instance, you can use a string quartet and modulate it by feeding a drum set as the source signal!

On the other hand, "where you can just play the keys and get the source tuned to the carrier frequency" describes quite accurately how a harmonizer works. The problem with this is that you need to know the exact frequency of the source. It needs to be a proper clean monophonic sound, otherwise the algorithm can't know how much it needs to pitch-shift the signal to reach each of the carrier frequencies.
What's more, in a harmonizer you usually don't specify the target frequencies manually, but just pre-define some scale for the harmonizer to work on. It then needs to figure out by itself which harmonies to actually create, which again only works if you start with a very clean signal.